# How to implement a speech bubble custom border in SL with a movable leader

Tags: silverlight, layout, custom-controls

Check out the following pic. This happens when you expand a folder in Mac OS X from its shortcut on the dock. I'd like to do something very similar in SL. And in case it's difficult to understand - the dock is on the right, with the folder-speech-bubble expanding up & out to the left. The folder contents would be icons out of frame in the upper-left.

[image: Mac OS X dock folder expansion]

The best I've come up with is including a xaml Path that makes up the "leader" portion of the bubble and placing it directly over the border of a canvas.  It looks like the following.

[image: Silverlight speech bubble]

The Path, being a separate element, doesn't "integrate" well with the Grid and causes two issues. If you look closely you'll see that there is a slight transparency and the Grid's border is subtly bleeding through. Something else that will crop up, if I use a border thickness > 1, is the line-end caps between the Path border and the Grid border won't be connected, they'll simply overlap looking chunky and unpolished.

What I need is a solution that allows me to slide the leader up & down the speech bubble (depending upon its context) and adapts to the issues explained above. I'd be happy with ideas, examples, and down right full implementations.

Comment: @otaku @denis Thanks for the help. I'll be looking at these today and choose the correct answer that best works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use the Border control. Just create a Path and shove it and the controls in a Canvas tag to be grouped. Then, the Path will be something like the below:

```
    <Path Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" Stroke="DarkGray" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="Silver" Opacity="0.5">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="0,10" IsClosed="True">
                    <ArcSegment SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="10,0" Size="10,10"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="90,0"/>
                    <ArcSegment SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="100,10" Size="10,10"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="100,90"/>
                    <ArcSegment SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="90,100" Size="10,10"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="10,100"/>
                    <ArcSegment SweepDirection="Clockwise" Point="0,90" Size="10,10"/>
                    <LineSegment x:Name="BottomOfCallOut" Point="0,70"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="-40,50"/>
                    <LineSegment x:Name="TopOfCallOut" Point="0,30"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

Then just use `PointAnimation` to move both `TopOfCallOut` and `BottomOfCallOut` along the Y-axis. In this example, I've made the base of the callout 40 points, so if you move `TopOfCallOut` from 0,30 to 0,10, just make sure you also put `BottomOfCallOut` to 0,50.

Comment: For my purposes this is the better solution because I need to move the entire "leader" up & down - e.g. I need to translate the entire triangle piece; so I move BottomOfCallOut, TopOfCallOut, and even CenterOfCallOut. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Also, my purposes don't require animation, so for others looking for a similar solution - you can also manipulate the coordinates directly. So doing TopOfCallOut.Point = new Point(TopOfCallOut.Point.X, TopOfCallOut.Point.Y + 10) works well too.

Comment: Hmm, you know, this misses one requirement that I didn't state. One of the reasons I needed to use a Border + Grid is the Width and Height adjusts the bubble's contents. Is there an easy way to do this w/o distorting the round corners and the leader?

Comment: It's not super easy, but basically it just means managing the LineSegements above. The ArcSegements can stay the same as they just start from wherever the LineSegment ends. It's just a lot of resizing as you go.

Comment: Yeah, I figured I'd have to manage the line segments manually ... was just hoping there was an easy way to scale the "box" portion of the bubble. Either way, your answer gets me pretty far. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I used same approach in TipBubble control (http://www.youpvp.com/blog/post/TipBubble-Tutorial.aspx). It works well in most cases but breaks down if you combine border and transparent background. To make bubble that works in that particular case you'd have to make it with single path. Just combine arc and line segments into one path. Or you could try rounded rectangle callout from Blend 4 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone still needs a Bubble in Silverlight, I've prepared a reusable control for this purpose.

I'm not allowed to post images here yet, but you can see the pictures, details and download the code from by blog post here: http://mikeshilkov.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/speech-bubble-control-in-sl/